# How to delay a js script loading

Tags: magento2, javascript, dom

One of my community modules is creating issues due to the fact he is loading too fast. When he is loading, the dom is not fully loaded yet.

From : `vendor/alma/alma-monthlypayments-magento2/view/frontend/web/js/view/catalog/badge.js`

```
var qtyNode = document.getElementById('qty');
qtyNode.addEventListener("input",function(){updateWidget()});
```

This is triggering cannot read property of null.

Any idea how to prevent this js file from loading while the dom isn't fully loaded ?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the JS in a define which includes domReady as below maybe?

```
define([
    'domReady'
], function (domReady) {
    domReady(function () {
        
        var qtyNode = document.getElementById('qty');
        qtyNode.addEventListener("input",function(){updateWidget()});

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `domReady!` dependency to define to delay code execution until DOM will be ready

```
define([
    'domReady!'
], function () {
    var qtyNode = document.getElementById('qty');
    qtyNode.addEventListener("input",function(){updateWidget()});

});
```